# Find intersecting rectangles groups

Tags: intersection

I've a list of rectangles in the form

```
{index, {centerX, centerY}, {width, height}}
```

I want to find intersecting rectangles list. I want to obtain a list on the form

```
{{indx...indy},{indt...indz}...}
```

Every element of this list is a list of rectangles that have at least an intersection in common, with transitive property: if rectangle 1 intersects rectangle 2 that intersect rectangle 3, these are a part of the same group.

If I've this situation in the image below, my intersecting list should be

```
{{1,2,10},{6},{7,5},{3},{4,8,9}}
```

(element order is not important). How can I accomplish this?

[image]

EDIT: There's a real sample data, with two groups and an isolated rectangle:

```
obj2 = {
   {1, {0, 0}, {1, 1}},
   {2, {0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}},
   {3, {3, 2}, {0.5, 0.6}},
   {4, {1.2, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.6}},
   {5, {2, -0.3}, {0.4, 0.4}},
   {6, {2.1, -0.4}, {0.3, 0.4}}
   };
```

Comment: If you have sample data that will save people some time, which is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm actually doing it, wait some minute please...

Comment: In v. 10 (which I do not have), it seems that `RegionQ[RegionIntersection[rect1,rect2]]` will be true if rect1 intersects with rect2.

Comment: @DavidCarraher it gives `True` even if the don't.

Comment: I assume that means that the empty region is indeed a region.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's first convert the input data to rectangles:

```
ToRectangle[{id_, center_, dimensions_}] := 
  {{id}, Rectangle[center - dimensions/2, center + dimensions/2]};

rectangles = ToRectangle /@ obj2;
```

Check if we have two groups and one isolated rectangle:

```
Graphics @ {
  {Text @@@ obj2},
  {Red, Opacity[1/4], Rest /@ rectangles}
}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ok, good. Let's combine the regions:

```
CombineRegions[regions_List] :=
  First /@ FixedPoint[
    Replace[
       #,
       {before___, {id1_, region1_}, inbetween___, {id2_, region2_}, after___} 
          /; Area @ RegionIntersection[region1, region2] > 0 
          :> {before, inbetween, after, {Join[id1, id2], RegionUnion[region1, region2]}}
    ] &,
    regions
  ];

CombineRegions @ rectangles
```

> ```
>  {{3}, {4, 1, 2}, {5, 6}}
> ```

While this produces the correct answer, it becomes quite slow when the number of rectangles grows. This is due to the pattern matcher restarting from the first position after each replacement, which causes a lot of redundant calls to `Area @ RegionIntersection[region1, region2]` (which is already quite slow in itself).

For large number of rectangles [ubpdqn's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58939/5485) is much faster.

Comment: very nice +1...I clearly misinterpreted the rectangles

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: +1, in this case `ReplaceRepeated` can also be used instead of `FixedPoint[Replace...`.

Comment: @Pickett I deliberately avoided `ReplaceRepeated` because `Rectangle` also comes with a list of two elements, and I wanted to make sure the whole expression got replaced instead of a subexpression.

Comment: @TeakeNutma Given the level of your answers I figured you had a reason for it, but I still think [it works](http://pastebin.com/kBtdPvri) in this particular case. The pattern of the rectangle is `Rectangle[{min,max},{min,max}]` and it can't match your pattern which is `{{el1,el2},{el3,el4}}`. It would be different if the pattern for a rectangle was `Rectangle[{{min,max},{min,max}}]`. Anyway it doesn't matter. Even if it was done just to be on the safe side it's, that's a viable reason too.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a graph theory approach:

```
ids = obj2[[All, 1]];
idToRectangleRules = #1 -> Rectangle[#2 - #3/2, #2 + #3/2] & @@@ obj2;

intersectingIdPairs = Select[
  Subsets[ids, {2}],
  Area @ RegionIntersection[# /. idToRectangleRules] > 0 &
];

overlappingIdGroups = ConnectedComponents @ Graph[ids, intersectingIdPairs]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 4}, {5, 6}, {3}}
> ```

Visualizing:

```
Graphics @ {
  { Opacity[0.5], Pink, Values @ idToRectangleRules },
  { Text[#1, RegionCentroid @ #2 ] & @@@ idToRectangleRules }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was alsto trying to think it as graph problem but I didn't know how to handle it...

Comment: +1 This is much faster than my answer, especially when the number of rectangles grows.

Comment: I took the liberty to refactor your code -- if it's not to your liking please rollback the edit.

Comment: @TeakeNutma thank you for edit. It is an improvement, so no need to rollback.

Comment: While this is already quite fast, it would be much faster still if `Area @ RegionIntersection` is replaced with a simple function that checks the bounds of the rectangles. (On my machine that's roughly 10^3 times faster).

Answer (score 8):

A method using the `FindClusters` function with a custom `DistanceFunction`:

```
distFunc =
   Function[{rect1, rect2},
            Block[{cpt1 = rect1[[2]], cpt2 = rect2[[2]],
                   dim1 = rect1[[3]]/2, dim2 = rect2[[3]]/2,
                   corners},
                  corners = cpt2 - cpt1 + # & /@
                              Flatten[
                                      Outer[List, {-1, 1} dim2[[1]], {-1, 1} dim2[[2]]],
                                      1] // Abs;
                  If[Or @@ (#1 < dim1[[1]] && #2 < dim1[[2]] & @@@ corners),
                     0, 1]
                 ]
           ];

FindClusters[obj2, DistanceFunction -> distFunc]
```

> ```
> {
>    {
>     {1, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
>     {2, {0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}}, 
>     {4, {1.2, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.6}}
>    }, 
>    {
>     {3, {3, 2}, {0.5, 0.6}}
>    }, 
>    {
>     {5, {2, -0.3}, {0.4, 0.4}}, 
>     {6, {2.1, -0.4}, {0.3, 0.4}}
>    }
>   }
> ```

Comment: +1. This is nice because it can works also with Mathematica versions less than 10 in which `RegionIntersection` and `RegionMeasure` are defined.

Comment: @Jepessen Thanks. Working for version<10 is exactly the point :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a somewhat quirky way using graph operations to perform the transitive closure.

```
(* object descriptors *)
obj = 
  {{1, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {2, {0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}}, {3, {3, 2}, {0.5,0.6}}, {4, {1.2, 0.5}, 
   {0.5, 0.6}}, {5, {2, -0.3}, {0.4, 0.4}}, {6, {2.1, -0.4}, {0.3, 0.4}}};

toRect[{_, {cx_, cy_}, {w_, h_}}] :=
  Rectangle[{cx - w/2, cy - h/2}, {cx + w/2, cy + h/2}]

(* taking care to avoid converting each descriptor to a rectangle more than once *)
intersects =
  Select[
    Subsets[{#[[1]], toRect[#]} & /@ obj, {2}], 
    RegionMeasure[RegionIntersection[#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]]] > 0 &
  ][[All, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}
> ```

```
connected = 
  ConnectedComponents[TransitiveReductionGraph[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ intersects]]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 4}, {5, 6}}
> ```

```
singletons = Complement[{#} & /@ Range@Length @ obj , {#} & /@ Flatten[intersects]]
```

> ```
> {{3}}
> ```

```
Join[connected, singletons]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 4}, {5, 6}, {3}}
> ```

#### Update

Öskå wants me to show the rectangles, so here they are.

```
toText[{indx_, cntr : {_, _}, _}] := Text[Style[indx, 18], cntr]

Graphics[{{Opacity[.4], toRect[#]} & /@ #, {White, toText[#]} & /@ #} & @ obj]
```

[image: rects]

Comment: @Öskå. I don't see any bracketing problem. I can draw the rectangles, but they will be the same as seen ubpdqn's answer. Do you still think I show them?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the advantage of using `TransitiveReductionGraph` instead of directly `Graph[vertices, edges]`?

Comment: @TeakeNutma. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. The OP asked for the transitive closure. `TransitiveReductionGraph` seemed an easy way to compute it.

Comment: Well, it's not as simple as ubpdqn's approach which gets the transitive closure more directly. So using `TransitiveReductionGraph` looks a bit redundant, and I was wondering whether it has e.g. speed benefits.

Comment: @TeakeNutma. Do not claim any speed benefits. I just thought it was an interesting variant that people might want to aware of.

Comment: Indeed `TransitiveReductionGraph` seems to be unnecessary. Dropping it should make no difference.